# Chrome Browser: Negative scroll on the top

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

I tried this trick to stop the negative scroll on chrome

```
html { overflow: hidden;}
body {overflow: auto;}
```

I have already in the above this:

```
html,body { height: 100%; }
```

but this one block the document and window objects scrollTop to 0.

how can i prevent the negative scroll without effect document and the window objects ?

i tried also this

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() < 0 ){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add also:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

To `body` & `html`

Comment: they have already been added, but this effect the window. the window scrollTop will be 0 at any position in the document

Comment: So you need to use `$('body').scrollTop()` instead. This happens because you not allowing `window` to have a scroll, only `body` element.

Comment: i tried it and i have this $('body').scrollTop() = 0

Comment: I can scroll the page but the value is 0 at any position.

Comment: @Salmen seems like this is known bug in Chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423935 :(

Comment: :(, there is noway to prevent the elastic effect on chrome?

Comment: @Salmen you can use one inner `div` inside it. Seems like bug is only affected to body: http://jsfiddle.net/doetruzo/